# Multiple exclusion patterns with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to select lines which do not match the specified pattern, where I have multiple patterns to exclude. As an example, I want to exclude lines which start with the keywords `apple` and `banana`:

```
$ grep -v '^apple' foo.txt | grep -v '^banana' -
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with one expression or one call to `grep`. I have tried the following, but they don't seem to work as hoped:

```
$ grep -v "^apple" -v "^banana" foo.txt
$ grep -v "^(apple|banana)" foo.txt
$ grep -v "(^apple)|(^banana)" foo.txt
```

What is a correct way to exclude multiple patterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify "alternate" matches, you have to include the "E" switch like:

```
$ grep -Ev "^(apple|banana)" foo.txt
$ grep -Ev "(^apple)|(^banana)" foo.txt
```

Either version above should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify multiple patterns with `-e`.

`grep -e '^apple' -e '^banana' -v foo.txt`

`grep -e '^apple' -e '^banana' foo.txt`